# Trying to write data from a dictionary to a file using a function where there is multiple key value pairs

Tags: python

I am trying to write the data for students in a class (their scores) to a file.
The program asks for the name of the class, the student's name and their score. These are used as arguments in the function `createclass` which creates a file with the name of the class. However, it only writes the data for one student into the file and does not write any more than one student into the file.

I would like to know how I can display more than one student where each student's name and score would show on a new line.

```
def createclass(chosenclass,studentname,score): 
    classoptions = 'Class {}'.format(chosenclass)
    with open(f'{classoptions}.txt', '+w') as file:
        data = {}
        data[studentname] = int(score)
        for key,value in data.items():
            studentdata = 'Name: {}, Score: {}/100'.format(key, value)
        file.write(studentdata)
    return file



print('Welcome to the Main Menu')
print('\n')
command = input('Please enter a command: ')
while command:
    if command == '6':
        print('Have a good day!')
        exit()
    elif command == '1':
        print('\n')
        askclass = input('Please enter your class: ')
        studentno = int(input('How many student\'s are in your class?: '))
        for i in range(0,studentno):
            askstudent = input('Please enter a student\'s full name: ')
            askscore = int(input('Please enter the student\'s score: '))
            createclass(askclass,askstudent,askscore)
            print('\n')
            print('Student Added')
    command = input('Please enter a command: ')
```

Comment: Open the file in append mode with in append mode with `open(f'{classoptions}.txt', 'a')`, then each time you call `createclass()` it will add a new line to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `createclass()` always overwrites the file, so only the last student is written.

You need to create the dict `data` outside `createclass` and pass it to `createclass` as an argument. Inside `createclass`, call `file.write(studentdata)` every iteration, not only the last time. The following code works:

```py
def createclass(chosenclass, data): 
    classoptions = 'Class {}'.format(chosenclass)
    with open(f'{classoptions}.txt', '+w') as file:
        for key,value in data.items():
            studentdata = 'Name: {}, Score: {}/100\n'.format(key, value)
            file.write(studentdata)
    return file



print('Welcome to the Main Menu')
print('\n')
command = input('Please enter a command: ')
while command:
    if command == '6':
        print('Have a good day!')
        exit()
    elif command == '1':
        print('\n')
        askclass = input('Please enter your class: ')
        studentno = int(input('How many student\'s are in your class?: '))
        data = {}
        for i in range(0,studentno):
            askstudent = input('Please enter a student\'s full name: ')
            askscore = int(input('Please enter the student\'s score: '))
            data[askstudent] = askscore
            print('\n')
            print('Student Added')
        createclass(askclass, data)
    command = input('Please enter a command: ')
```

Another solution is to open the file in append mode:

```py
    with open(f'{classoptions}.txt', 'a') as file:
        data = {}
        data[studentname] = int(score)
        for key,value in data.items():
            studentdata = 'Name: {}, Score: {}/100\n'.format(key, value)
        file.write(studentdata)
```